# How can I produce Japanese quotation marks?

Tags: punctuation

How can I produce the sort of Japanese quotation marks shown on this book page?

[image]

I tried ″英語″ but in documents on my computer (Microsoft Word, plain text) it comes out looking like this screenshot: [image] where 1) both marks are in the same direction rather than pointing in toward each other and catty-corner to each other (mirrored), and 2) my academic advisor says there is too much blank space between the left quotation mark and the text inside it (that typographical symbol cannot be scooted over, in the same way as the space on the outer sides of「」cannot be pushed in to make a word on the outside closer to it:「」without spaces on either side). This is for an academic paper of which I will pass out a copy for the audience to read along during the presentation, so it ought to match the original quotation from the book.

I looked in the character viewer on my MacBook Air, and I checked [Japanese typographic symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_typographic_symbols) on Wikipedia, but I could not find anything else that looks like this mirrored set of quotation marks.

---

Edit:

U+301F and U+301D used together don't seem to match in size and thickness (even when they are in the same font size):

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think those are `〝` U+301D and `〟` U+301F:

> 〝英語〟および

Depending on the font, you may be able to use `“` U+201C and `”` U+201D in 縦書き.

Comment: Thank you. In MS Word and in a text file, U+301F comes out looking smaller and thinner than U+301D even when they are the same font size (see screenshot I added into the question). Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: This is due to your font and/or Microsoft Word. Using the IPAMincho or TakaoMincho in Libreoffice on my Linux machine, I do not get the same result...

Comment: @seijitsu 〝 〟 of MS明朝 font, which I guess you are using in the sample image, work fine usually. Isn't it about Settings of AutoCorrect or something in Word or OSX? The pair of 〝 〟 is called 「ダブルミニュート」, 「爪括弧」, 「チョンチョン」 or 「ノノカギ」 in Japanese. These words might be helpful to search a solution on internet.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I had copied and pasted from the answer above, which had created some sort of formatting. I cleared formatting and the MS明朝 switched into looking correct.